# MySQL get max and min value of a field for last 5 minutes timestamp

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have a script which inserts many entries at a MySQL table at the same time. This means I'm having >100 entries with the very same timestamp, another >100 entries with that timestamp plus 1 second...

This script is being launched time to time, so I'm getting a los of entries during a couple of minutes each time the script is launched. I want to retrieve the max and min value for a certain field MYFIELD having a look just at the last 5 minutes of the timestamp, so I can get that min and max values from the last script execution.

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find the last timestamp:

```
SELECT MAX(timestamp)
FROM your_table;
```

And use it to get MIN and MAX:

```
SELECT MIN(myfield), MAX(myfield)
FROM your_table
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(timestamp) as max FROM your_table) t ON TRUE
WHERE timestamp >= (max - interval 5 MINUTE);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add a column (say insert_timestamp) to track the row inserted timestamp. so the query will be as simple as

```
select min(myfield), max(myfield) 
from mytable
where insert_timestamp between now() and (now() - interval 5 MINUTE)
```

Comment: Why can't I just use that over the timestamp field? It is not possible for me to change the script in order to add another column.

Comment: well I don't think that there's any way you could do that without tracking the inserted time.